# Count letters in a text file

Tags: python

I am a beginner python programmer and I am trying to make a program which counts the numbers of letters in a text file. Here is what I've got so far:

```
import string 
text = open('text.txt')
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
for i in text:
  text_lower = i.lower()
  text_nospace = text_lower.replace(" ", "")
  text_nopunctuation = text_nospace.strip(string.punctuation)
  for a in letters:
    if a in text_nopunctuation:
      num = text_nopunctuation.count(a)
      print(a, num)
```

If the text file contains `hello bob`, I want the output to be:

```
b 2
e 1
h 1
l 2
o 2
```

My problem is that it doesn't work properly when the text file contains more than one line of text or has punctuation.

Answer (score 12):

This is very readable way to accomplish what you want using [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import Counter

with open('text.txt') as f:
    print Counter(letter for line in f 
                  for letter in line.lower() 
                  if letter in ascii_lowercase)
```

You can iterate the resulting dict to print it in the format that you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
fp=open('text.txt','r')
file_list=fp.readlines()
print file_list
freqs = {}
for line in file_list:
    line = filter(lambda x: x in string.letters, line.lower())
    for char in line:
        if char in freqs:
            freqs[char] += 1
        else:
            freqs[char] = 1

print freqs
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
text = 'aaaaabbbbbccccc'
c = Counter(text)
print c
```

It prints:

```
Counter({'a': 5, 'c': 5, 'b': 5})
```

Your `text` variable should be:

```
import string
text = open('text.txt').read()
# Filter all characters that are not letters.
text = filter(lambda x: x in string.letters, text.lower())
```

For getting the output you need:

```
for letter, repetitions in c.iteritems():
    print letter, repetitions
```

In my example it prints:

```
a 5
c 5
b 5
```

For more information [Counters doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 1):

Using re:

```
import re

context, m = 'some file to search or text', {}
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
for i in range(len(letters)):
  m[letters[i]] = len(re.findall('{0}'.format(letters[i]), context))
  print '{0} -> {1}'.format(letters[i], m[letters[i]])
```

It is much more elegant and clean with Counter nonetheless.

Comment: This works quite well for me except I can't get it to open my text file properly. I tried replacing the 'some file to search or text' bit with open('text.txt') but it didn't work. I keep getting a need more than one to unpack error. Also I don't really understand what you are making the variables context and m. Could you help me out?

Comment: Sure thing. Just use:
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file: context = file.read()
You probably ran into python's famous yield iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, if you want to do it without using `Counter`, here's another very short way, using list comprehension and the `dict` builtin:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
with open("text.txt") as f:
    text = f.read().lower()
    print dict((l, text.count(l)) for l in letters)
```

`f.read()` will read the content of the entire file into the `text` variable (might be a bad idea, if the file is really large); then we use a list comprehension to create a list of tuples `(letter, count in text)` and convert this list of tuples to a dictionary. With Python 2.7+ you can also use `{l: text.count(l) for l in letters}`, which is even shorter and a bit more readable.

Note, however, that this will search the text multiple times, once for each letter, whereas `Counter` scans it only once and updates the counts for all the letters in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the problem into two simpler tasks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput # accept input from stdin and/or files specified at command-line
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
from string import ascii_lowercase

# 1. count frequencies of all characters (bytes on Python 2)
freq = Counter(chain.from_iterable(fileinput.input())) # read one line at a time

# 2. print frequencies of ascii letters
for c in ascii_lowercase:
     n = freq[c] + freq[c.upper()] # merge lower- and upper-case occurrences
     if n != 0:
        print(c, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

read_chunk_size = 65536

freq = defaultdict(int)
for c in sys.stdin.read(read_chunk_size):
    freq[ord(c.lower())] += 1

for symbol, count in sorted(freq.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True):
    print(chr(symbol), count)
```

It outputs the symbols most frequent to the least.

The character counting loop is O(1) complexity and can handle arbitrarily large files because it reads the file in `read_chunk_size` chunks.

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys

def main():
    try:
         fileCountAllLetters = file(sys.argv[1], 'r')
         print "Count all your letters: ", len(fileCountAllLetters.read())
    except IndexError:
         print "You forget add file in argument!"
    except IOError:
         print "File like this not your folder!"

main()
```

> python file.py countlettersfile.txt