# counting letters in a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to do this problem

Write a program that reads a file named text.txt and prints the following to the
screen:

 The number of characters in that file

 The number of letters in that file

 The number of uppercase letters in that file

 The number of vowels in that file

I have gotten this so far but I am stuck on step 2 this is what I got so far.

```
file = open('text.txt', 'r')
lineC = 0
chC = 0
lowC = 0
vowC = 0
capsC = 0
for line in file:
    for ch in line:
        words = line.split()
        lineC += 1
        chC += len(ch)
for letters in file:
        for ch in line:
print("Charcter Count = " + str(chC))
print("Letter Count = " + str(num))
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647707/count-letters-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above uses regular expressions, which are very useful and worth learning about if you haven't used them before. Bunji's code is also more efficient, as looping through characters in a string in Python is relatively slow.

However, if you want to try doing this using just Python, take a look at the code below.  A couple of points: First, wrap your `open()` inside a `using` statement, which will automatically call `close()` on the file when you are finished. Next, notice that Python lets you use the `in` keyword in all kinds of interesting ways. Anything that is a sequence can be "in-ed", including strings. You could replace all of the `string.xxx` lines with your own string if you would like.

```
import string

chars = []

with open("notes.txt", "r") as f:
    for c in f.read():
        chars.append(c)


num_chars = len(chars)

num_upper = 0;
num_vowels = 0;
num_letters = 0

vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
for c in chars:
    if c in vowels:
        num_vowels += 1
    if c in string.ascii_uppercase:
        num_upper += 1
    if c in string.ascii_letters:
        num_letters += 1

print(num_chars)
print(num_letters)
print(num_upper)
print(num_vowels)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding a quicker option. I realize my example could be quite slow for large files. If you wanted to make it even faster you could combine your for loops into one so you check if a character is a vowel, letter, etc. while you're appending to the chars list.  That way you only have to iterate through it once.

Comment: @bunji Your code is quicker than mine. Sorry if I didn't make that clear in my answer. RegEx tests strings faster than loops in most languages, especially Python.  I didn't use them in my answer as based on the question it seems that OP is new to Python, and perhaps programming, and RegExps are quite a bit different (really there own sub-language). I didn't really start using them until after I was already comfortable with coding.

Comment: Ok Cool seeing the one Brian posted I get it for the most part. I'm very new to python and still trying to remember/figure stuff out. In class I don't think we have used "chars.append(c)" yet but I really appreciate the help from the both of you. Also is there another way to get uppercase or do I always use "string.ascii"?

Comment: @David string.ascii_xxx is a *constant*, which is basically a shortcut for a commonly used value that won't ever change. Each of the constants inside string is an actual string, so you could use your own. You don't even need to create a string variable, you can use a literal such as `c in "ABCDEFG..."`.  Using a variable name (or constant) just makes the code a little cleaner. As for `chars.append(c)`. Learn the `append()` method. You will use it more than anything else when learning Python. It simply adds the item (`c` in this case) to the end of a list.

Comment: @David Also, if you feel that either me or Bunju has answered your question, please accept one of the answers by clicking on the green check box (unless you want a better or different answer). Finally when you mention someone specifically in a comment, use @[name] inside the comment so that the person you are talking about will be notified. Thanks. Hope your enjoying Python. I'm taking a college class as well that is using it.

Comment: @BrianHVB . My bad. You were clear I was just reading your answer way too late at night and misread the first sentence.  That being said, I'm not entirely sure how re.findall operates if it doesn't iterate over the string in some way.  Do you know why re.findall is faster than a loop (even when its called 4 times like in my example?).  Actually, I should probably post this as a separate question.  

EDIT:

I found an answer to my question [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122440/how-do-regular-expressions-actually-work)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using regular expressions. Find all occurrences of your pattern as your list and then finding the length of that list.

```
import re
with open('text.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    characters = len(re.findall('\S', text))
    letters = len(re.findall('[A-Za-z]', text))
    uppercase = len(re.findall('[A-Z]', text))
    vowels = len(re.findall('[AEIOUYaeiouy]', text))
```